# Unable to access cross domain web service in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to post some data to an express.js server. The client side is a cordova app. I can successfully post content using a browser but unable to do so using the cordova app. 
When I attempt, I get an error: `POST https://192.xx.x.1:8081/test 404 (Not Found).` Upon using the Chrome device inspector the following is seen

```
Request URL:https://192.xx.x.1:8081/test
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache)
```

Here are few more things that I have added:

In config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

The cordova whitelist plugin is already installed.

In index.html and scan.html pages, I have added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I have also made sure that the AndroidManifest.xml file contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Here is the code for the POST request

> ```
>   $.ajax({
>       type       : "POST",
>       url        : app.url,
>       crossDomain: true,
>       data       : {username : 'asd', password : 'sadsfa'},
>       dataType   : 'json',
>       success    : function(response) {
>           $('#result').text("response");
>       },
>       error      : function(error) {
>           alert(JSON.stringify(error));
>
>       }       });
> ```

Finally I tried clearing the application cache. Nothing works. None of the request reaches the server side. What am I missing out?

Comment: app.url  -- is this a php file ??-- if so add in to that php file (header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');) and you shouldn't get the access issue. also test file should have an extension too like test.php so in you ajax it should be (url        : test.php) that's probably why it cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml file?

Also, if you are using jQuery Mobile as your UI framework, do a `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;` when you receive the `deviceready` notification.